# How do I export a gSuite user's email when I'm a delegate for their account

Tags: google-workspace

I'm trying to find a way to export the emails of a current employee without them knowing. I'm currently a delegate on the account and am using GAM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are superadmin then you should look into either Google Vault which is the immutable record of emails see [doc](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462365?hl=en) or you should use Got Your Back [here](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back) written by Jay0lee who wrote GAM. GYB exports to MBOX though so if you want to share the emails with someone who for whatever reason can't read MBOX then you will need an MBOX to PST converter of which there are many online. I have used the one from Systools effectively [link](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/mbox-converter.html).  Or you can export by GYB and then import into a different gmail account which is quite useful for some types of investigation.

If you are merely a delegate then there is no easy way.